# line/bar graph with respect to day,week,month and year iPhone

Tags: iphone

i wanna to make a bar/line graph showing progress of the body weight wrto day,week,month and year,all in a segmentd control.
the body weight are shown as increment of 20 in X axis(20,40,60 etc.) and the y value should be 1,2,3 etc irrespective of the segmented control values. If the segmened control value is chosen as day, the y value will read as 1 day, 2 day etc. and if it is week,the y value would be 1 week, 2 week and so on.

for eg: if the weight for the 1 day is 20, 2nd day is 30 and for 3rd day is 25, then the  graph sould be as follows..(line graph also accepted)
[image: Bar Graph for BodyWeight vs day]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to generate a bar graph i think is..

http://www.field-theory.org/articles/powerplot/example.html

or for all types of graph see..

http://www.keepedge.com/products/iphone_charting/

Answer (score 1):

Check CorePlot library it's quite decent and simple to use. 
[CorePlot plot examples](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/PlotExamples)

Other way is draw the bar manually, using CoreGraphics. Then you are just drawing CGRects with a proper height. It's more customizable but more coding too.

Answer (score 1):

Check this :
http://iphoneapplicationdevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/03/iphone-sdk-how-to-draw-bar-charts-using.html

even U can find barchart sample program in core-plot folder ->examples ->CpTestApp .